# Within bootstrap theme, print radio item with label and input as siblings instead of parent -> child

Tags: theming, 8

By default, Bootstrap will render the `input` radio and checkbox elements as children of the `label`.  This is done in `Drupal\bootstrap\Plugin\Preprocess\FormElement`, starting at line 45:

```
// Place single checkboxes and radios in the label field.
if (($checkbox || $radio)) {
  $label = Element::create($variables['label']);
  $children = &$label->getProperty('children', '');
```

In some instances, I don't want these printed as siblings - how can I undo this?  `form-element.html.twig` isn't helpful unless I can somehow print the children first e.g. `{{ label.#children }}` and then twig will know not to print them again.  Not sure if that solution is even possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At first I was going to say `hook_form_alter`, but when I started digging into the Bootstrap theme I found they've created their own plugin system. I would checkout this page, you might be able to get to the render array by creating a Bootstrap theme plugin: https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs%21plugins%21Form.md/group/plugins_form/8

Comment: I posted a full answer with code samples but you are correct, the solution is to extend the appropriate `\Preprocess\[element name]`

Answer (score 0):

As @icicleking states, bootstrap uses theme plugins that can be extended.  So that we have a thorough answer for what I did I'll post it separately here.

Extend `\Drupal\bootstrap\Plugin\Preprocess\FormElement`.  There's only one method, `preprocessElement`.  In my case I replaced the following:

```
// Place single checkboxes and radios in the label field.
if (($checkbox || $radio)) {
  $label = Element::create($variables['label']);
```

with

```
// Place single checkboxes and radios in the label field.
if (($checkbox || $radio) && !$element->hasProperty('no_wrap_label')) {
  $label = Element::create($variables['label']);
```

Then you can use the `no_wrap_label` property on any element that you don't want to be wrapped inside a label, I'm using `hook_preprocess_form_element`:

```
function your_module_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['name'] == 'field_field_name') {
    $variables['element']['#no_wrap_label'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that mean we have to modify bootstrap core theme? code at https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/2644016 is for 7 (although Closed (won't fix) by module author)
more discussion at https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/104517 https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317256 https://www.thirdandgrove.com/theming-form-elements-drupal-8